# How can I move lines or folded regions before or after other folded regions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, folding

Assume we have a folded region, let's say of 50 rows. Let's call it "**TheRegion**".

After TheRegion we've got a line. Let's call it "**TheLine**".

Now I want to **move TheLine before TheRegion** without cut-and-paste it but with the "moving the line up and down" feature.

If a do the "move-the-line-up" command TheRegion unfolds and TheLine moves to the 49th line of TheRegion...

This in not what I want.
**I want TheLine moves *before* TheRegion** without unfolding it...

The same problem if I try to move a folded region or an unfolded selection before or after a folded region...

How can this be done with VS Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible.

See this feature request issue: [[folding] Move line up/down should skip over folded regions or folded sections #63972](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/63972). (For your reference / learning purposes, this was found simply by googling "`github vscode issues move line fold`").

You can give the issue a thumbs up to show support for it, and subscribe to get notified of discussion and updates. But please don't make noisy "+1" or "bump" comments.

I am not aware of any workarounds.